# Unable to run executable files

Tags: release-freya, system, software-installation

I downloaded Foxit Reader (a PDF reader) and Popcorn time. To install them, running an executable file is needed, but even if I give them the permission to be executed by everyone (Not just the root user), After double clicking or choosing 'Run' option nothing happens.
I tried

```
sudo chmod +x filename
```

and then running it, even that didn't work. I really don't know why.

If I try to run them through the terminal (Using 'sh' command or by just typing the name of the executable file) I get an error saying the no such directory exists.

I downloaded new file manager (PCManFM), When i double clicked the executable file, a pop up appered asking me to 'Execute', 'Execute in Terminal' or 'Cancel', of course non of the options worked.
I'm running Elementary OS 0.3.2 64bit

Comment: try droping the excutable file in the terminal and press enter a look if it drops any error, if it does, post the output here

Comment: Did you by chance download the 32 bit binaries? The 'no such directory exists' error on executable files tends to happen because of exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installation as on https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/thanks.php?product=Foxit-Reader&platform=Linux-64-bit&version=1.1.0.0225&package_type=run&language=English advised?

filename.run executable will be start with ./filename.run
Also you can start it from filemanager with right click extract.
I have tested Foxit Reader without problems.